# Bootstrap alternative for Storefront

Tags: wordpress, storefront

I use bootstrap for my website which uses storefront child theme. However, bootstrap.css has many conflicts which those in storefront.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/21213

I found some tutorials that show the fix for boostrap-woocommerce conflict. However, it does not work for Storefront

Are there any good alternatives that I can use for styling? Or how do you guys avoid those conflicts? Thanks

Comment: Your question is much subjective. Please, send us a more objective question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: True, I know there are lots of css framework you can use. I just ask which one you prefer. There is no right or wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

you should use bootstrap's ['Customize and download'](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/) tool

this should help you deal with conflicts. this tool is not available for version 4 but you can do in manually, [check the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming/)